# mysql positive and negative tag filtering

Tags: php, mysql, tags, filtering

I have a list of sites that are all tagged. I am getting stumped on a query to use that is fast and will allow "negative" tags. In other words, like when you search for Google saying -yahoo would search for results that don't contain yahoo.

The problem I'm having is the tags are on the site side. So if the user searches for yahoo, the site is tagged -yahoo, so it won't show up with the results even if it matches on every other tag.

The structure of the tables is:

Sites:
ID|other stuff..

Tags:
ID|Tag (where tag is either yahoo or -yahoo)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably rework the tags table so there's a ratings field, e.g. a simple

```
id | tag | rating (bit)
```

so you only store "yahoo" in the `tag` field, and keep the +/- stuff in the ratings field.

```
... WHERE tag='yahoo' AND rating=XXX
```

If you can't rework, then you'll have to modify your where clauses

```
... WHERE tag='yahoo' OR tag='-yahoo'
```